# What is the symbolism behind the ten heads of Ravana?

Tags: ravana, symbolism

*Ravana* is depicted to have ten heads. Is there any symbolism behind this?

Comment: related question http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2280/did-ravana-have-ten-heads

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande: Thanks for the link. The second answer there does go into symbolism but sounds more like an opinion as it uses no references. Also, symbolism does not have to be binary with it being real. Both, real and unreal events can have symbolism.

Comment: The ten heads refer to the ten senses. Five jnanendriyas and five karmendriyas. Ravana refers to the sensory world. Rama refers to Atman, while Sita refers to Mind. Right now your mind has been taken hostage by the senses. Your Atman is on the quest to get it back. :) This is my understanding adapted from Sai Baba's teachings.

Comment: @Sai: Awesome interpretation. You could post it as an answer if you have references. Otherwise, it is not accepted.